# angular Animations not working at all

Tags: css, angularjs

I cant seem to get my animations to work at all.
Below is my code, I have tried to change versions that too did not help.

This is the html:

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sm nav-no-br mb10" id="flightChooseTab">
        <li ng-class="{ 'active' : Register != true }">
            <a ng-click="Register = false">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ 'active' : Register == true }">
            <a ng-click="Register = true" class="">New User</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-animate="'am-flip-x'" ng-if="Register != true">
        <div class="form-group form-group-icon-left">
            <i class="fa fa-user input-icon input-icon-show"></i>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. johndoe@gmail.com" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-icon-left">
            <i class="fa fa-lock input-icon input-icon-show"></i>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="my secret password" />
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-animate="'am-flip-x'" ng-if="Register == true">
        <div class="form-group form-group-icon-left">
            <i class="fa fa-user input-icon input-icon-show"></i>
            <label>Full Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. John Doe" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-icon-left">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope input-icon input-icon-show"></i>
            <label>Emai</label>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. johndoe@gmail.com" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-icon-left">
            <i class="fa fa-lock input-icon input-icon-show"></i>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="my secret password" />

            <i class="fa fa-lock input-icon input-icon-show"></i>
            <label>Repeat Password</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="my secret password" />
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Sign up" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried to change to use this approach :

```
class="col-md-4 am-flip-x"
```

and:
    ng-animate="am-flip-x"

Here is my css for the flip:

```
.am-flip-x {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
          animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
          animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
          animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.am-flip-x.am-flip-x-add,
.am-flip-x.ng-hide-remove,
.am-flip-x.ng-move {
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInXBounce;
          animation-name: flipInXBounce;
}
.am-flip-x.am-flip-x-remove,
.am-flip-x.ng-hide {
  -webkit-animation-name: flipOutX;
          animation-name: flipOutX;
}
.am-flip-x.ng-enter {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInXBounce;
          animation-name: flipInXBounce;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
          animation-play-state: paused;
}
.am-flip-x.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
          animation-play-state: running;
}
.am-flip-x.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation-name: flipOutX;
          animation-name: flipOutX;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
          animation-play-state: paused;
}
.am-flip-x.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
          animation-play-state: running;
}
```

My app code is initialized:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ui-rangeSlider',  'infinite-scroll', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.helpers.dimensions', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.helpers.dateParser', 'ng-multi-select', "revolunet.stepper"]).controller('HomeController', ["$scope", "$http", "$location", "$filter", function ($scope, $http, $location, $filter) { //Code Here }]);
```

Here are my references for angular, angular strap, jquery, angular animation:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<script  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.2.4/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.2.4/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you create a plunkr?

Comment: @jax , jme11 got me on the right path thanks, it was only my versions that were messing me around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ViJyT18Dl44qhjbleVS?p=preview)

There are a couple of issues with both your markup and your CSS:

1. Make sure you are loading the correct versions of ngAnimate and ngRoute.  In your question, you have Angular 1.3.15 but you're using the 1.4 release candidate for animate and route.
2. Make sure that you're loading the stylesheet for the animations (I can't tell because you don't have a demo just some snippets).
3. You need to add the class to the element that you want to animate.
4. For keyframe animations, you don't use the 'active' class, known as the *destination CSS class*, since the keyframe will take charge of the animation.
5. ng-If only animates enter and leave.  You can see the directive support in the table in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 am-flip-x" ng-if="register !== true">
```

**CSS:**

```
/*additional css and animation keyframes omitted for brevity*/
.am-flip-x {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
          animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
          animation-timing-function: ease;
}

.am-flip-x.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
          animation-name: flipInX;
}
.am-flip-x.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation-name: flipOutX;
          animation-name: flipOutX;
}
```

Comment: thanks allot for the help it seems that the problem was the version difference of the file, i forgot to add the keyframes to the snippets. but all the rest was fine, adding the correct versions and and returning the css to the class tag fixed thing up, again i say thank you good sir for your time and effort